# Why is the voltage gain in a fixed bias circuit not the same as l calculated?

Tags: bjt, bias

In this circuit below: ( I simulated in Multisim )

[image]

I measured the DC response in simulation as:

```
  Ic  = 3.73 mA
  Ib  = 15.7 uA
  Vc  = 11.3 mV
  Vbe = 824  mV
```

I calculated re (ac emitter resistance)

```
  re  = 25mV/Ic
      = 25mV/3.73 mA
      = 6.67 ohm
```

I calculated voltage gain from

```
   A  =  (R1//R3)/re
      =  4761/6.67
      = 713
```

I checked the graph in simulation. I found that voltage gain is not around 700, but rather around 300.  Why don't they match?

Comment: How did you found Vc?

Comment: Something is wrong here....what is the simulation result for the voltage Vce across the transistor? More than that, how did you simulate the gain? AC or Tran anylysis?

Comment: @Antonio51 I found Vc by first I apply ac signal = 0 V and I measured DC response.

Comment: sorry I simulated again and I found that Vce = 11.3 V

Comment: Ok. But you wrote 11.3 **mV** in the question ...

Comment: @ Antonio51 I'm sorry . Why voltage gain not the same as I calculated . Where is wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. It is obvious that your value of re is a little too low. Remember that , for all BJT (and others), you have a "resistance wiring" for E, B, C. If it is only 3 Ohms (resistor feedback), then your re = ~ 10 Ohm. So, simulating again gives 394 with my simulator. Note also that there is a large dispersion on beta ...

Comment: @Antonio51 I have guestion. What is dispersion on beta? So what cause my result not match with simulation.

Comment: Beta is generally "known", for one model device, with a relative uncertainty of "50%". I "interpret" as follow: if "mean beta"  = 200, then 100 < beta < 300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why voltage gain in fixed bias circuit not same as l calculated?*

A pretty good approximation to \$\pi\$ is \$\frac{22}{7}\$ (it's in error by about 0.04%) so, it's a useful and reliable engineering approximation.

Predicting the gain of a BJT circuit that doesn't employ emitter degeneration or some other kind of feedback is like approximating \$\pi\$ to \$\sqrt2\$.

Real life and over-simplistic formulas just don't tally very well at all. Even sophisticated models of BJTs (like [Gummel-Poon](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/rottinger/node61.html)) are still only approximations and, the more you push the circuit application to the extremes of what is common sense, the more inaccurate the model is.

[All models are wrong, but some are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong) is a quote from the statistician George Box. It very much applies here.

Comment: So my calculation is correct right ? But in my calculation it's approximation.

Comment: Your calculation is just a calculation and not a representation of real-life @Heroz. Realistically (within the bounds of calculating emitter resistance), it does not take into account that Ic is modulated by the signal and therefore emitter resistance is modulated by the signal. The trick is knowing when to use a simple formula and when to use a sophisticated model and, the even cleverer trick is knowing when not to trust the results of a sophisticated model.

Comment: I am sure, the given explanation cannot be the reason for such a big discreapency.

Comment: @LvW well my sim indicates a voltage gain of about 500. But the real point here is that trying to get a sim to predict what the gain might be of a BJT configuration that is problematic is just asking for trouble. If I changed models to Mextram I get a gain of about 300.

Comment: I do not know about Mextram - is it a SPICE-based program and does it include a detailed tansistor model for the 2N2222 (Gummel-Poon)?

Comment: @LvW: https://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/models/bipolar-models/mextram/mextramdefinition_504.7.pdf

Comment: Andy aka, thank you for the link - it is interesting. Because mextram uses its own model we cannot automatically assume that the results would be identical to SPICE simulations.

Comment: @LvW it's a bit of a minefield unless you are simulating circuits that are of a more normal design.

Comment: @Andyaka So it means that my calculation method is not suitable for this circuit therefore it can not predict gain in this circuit .

Comment: @Heroz your circuit design is not great. It doesn't respect undesirable aspects of BJT characteristics that will bite you in the leg. BJT (and MOSFET) circuits are very easy to get wrong and produce garbage one day and suddenly good results (temporarily) on another day at a different temperature. Nobody experienced would design your circuit without emitter degeneration or some form of negative feedback to stabilize performance. When that's done, all the simulations will agree with your calculations within a range of maybe +/- 20%. But, you will be looking at a max voltage gain of below 100.

Comment: To get a real circuit with a gain of over 600, you would use two transistors for example. Anyone who says you can reliably get this voltage gain from 1 transistor is blowing smoke up nasty places. And, of course, simulations of transistor circuits that are on the knife edge are bound to produce radically different results.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you very much . I have one question but why simulation can show result of this circuit ? Does simulation have equation for this circuit that can predict gain ?

Comment: @Heroz you need to look into how a simulator uses the Gummel-Poon model. I am no expert. There is a link above I gave to LvW that may be of use. For me, I am satisfied that simulation is a very useful tool but, you need to use it carefully.

Comment: @LvW SPICE doesn't presuppose any one model. You can choose the model to use for any particular component - it's only a matter of what models are available in a given SPICE implementation. Most industry tools either support the Mextram model, or are extensible so that it can be added by the end user.

Comment: @Andyaka There are some superbeta discrete transistors that would provide DC gains that high in a single stage amplifier circuits, but I'm not sure if any of them are still made. There's not much need for them, as higher fT, better noise figure transistors are available that allow the single stage to be split across two or three stages without losing performance. IIRC Mr Carlson's capacitor leakage tester uses one of those superbetas, in a nod to superbeta op-amp input stage designs I bet. Central Semi is the last place still making them.

Comment: @Heroz The maximum theoretical gain for a grounded emitter, mid supply biased, single transistor is equal to 20 * Vcc. So for a supply voltage of say 50 V the maximum gain would be something approaching 1000. Don't let anybody tell you otherwise! An example of a transistor that can tolerate a 50 V collector-Emitter voltage would be the BC546.

Comment: @James please make this comment an answer and note that when I say (in a comment above) the max gain should be below 100, I'm talking about a situation that is self-contained and reliable. Of course you can get higher gains (on a good day) but they do not make reliable single transistor amplifiers. Of course, if you have a reliable single transistor circuit that can achieve a gain of 1000 you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Andyaka My previous comment was in response to your "smoke blowing" comment. Of course, the op's circuit is not a practical circuit and would never be used in a real life application. Also, the grounded emitter amplifier (bypassed emitter) I mention is probably also best avoided due to high distortion. However, the concept of single transistor amplifiers with gains greater than  600 is entirely feasible. I do not intend to post such a circuit as an answer as it would be a long way from a relevant answer to the op's question.

Comment: @James you are giving the impression that it is feasible when clearly, for normal reliable circuits, it isn't.

Comment: @Andyaka Please re-read my last comment. I purposely use expressions such as "not a practical circuit " and "best avoided" and refer to "the concept of single transistor amplifiers with gains greater than 600 is entirely feasible". It's always better to respond to what has actually been said rather than the subjective impression which you as an individual might perceive.

Answer (score 1):

Collector current of a transistor rises by about 4% for every 1 mV rise in Vbe voltage.

So with no input signal and a collector current of 3.73 mA, there should be 18.65 V across R1 (the collector resistor). If Vbe increases by 1 mV then Ic should increase to about 3.73 mA * 1.04 = 3.8792 mA dropping 19.396 V across R1. If Vbe decreases by 1 mV then Ic should decrease to about 3.73 mA/1.04 = 3.5865 mA dropping 17.93 V across R1.

The peak to peak collector voltage swing for a 2 mV peak to peak base swing is then 19.396 V - 17.93 V = 1.466 V.

Voltage gain = 1.466 V/ 2 mV = 733 which is pretty close to your (R1//R3)/re calculation.

Can you check on your simulation that there is actually 2 mV ptop at the transistors base.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Ok, time for an exception.</sub>
The reason you are not getting a reasonable agreement between the simulated voltage ratio and the computed voltage gain is because you are using the wrong formula for the gain, but most importantly the wrong model for the BJT.
For a fixed bias amplifier like this the correct (and overkill formula) should be

$$Av = - \alpha * (R_{C} // R_{Load} // R_{B}) / r_e$$

where

$$re = Vth / Ie = k T / (q Ie)$$
$$\alpha = 0.996$$
(for my BJT with a gain of 320, oops I mean 230), and T is the temperature you run the simulation at.

Now, these are almost all *very minor points*, as we shall see in the simulations, but they introduce a series of minor corrections that help in getting a better agreement, **after** the major point is addressed. (Moreover, I decided to completely disregard the reactances of the capacitors and the voltage divider at the input mesh. They won't make and tangible difference and unlikely the other parameters above would have complicated the formula quite a bit for... nothing.)

This is an LTSpice simulation using the 2N2222 model provided in LTSpice.

[image: advanced model]

We can see that the gain computing different variants of the same simplified formula do not give acceptable approximations of the simulated voltage gain. Note that I have set the temperature to 27°C and I am using the correct value of Vth for that temperature.

[image: advanced results]

The red curve uses your approximation. The two brown curves below it are using the 'correct' formula with the correct Vth, Ie and the parallel with Rb. The light gray one uses alpha, just to show how little effect it bears. But still...
The purple curve at the bottom is the simulated ratio of voltages. I subtracted the quiescent values (there probably is a smarter way to do it, but I am a lazy *****rd.)
As you can see, even in LTSpice there is an unacceptably discrepancy between computed values and simulated ratio of voltages. We can see it in all its painful glory here:

[image]

This is completely unsatisfactory. We should demand to speak with the manager.

**So, what is the 'major point'?**
The major point is that the above formula is just a *rule of thumb*, an approximation that in the form above is *computed from the most basic model of BJT*. Therefore, if you want to see an agreement between simulated voltage amplification and the amplification computed using the most basic model of BJT you need to... use the most basic model of BJT. Did I say "most basic model of BJT" too many times?

LTSpice allows you to do that by creating a new model using the default NPN transistor. You just need to specify the beta. IIRC the beta of the 2N2222 in LTSpice is 320 (your simulator might use a different value). Heck, I used myself a different value because I flipped the digits while typing, so we will have to to with a beta of 230 (alpha does not change appreciably). - I will redo the simulation with the correct value of beta another time.

```
.model simpleBJT NPN (BF=230)
```

Note that with this model , the ratio of Ic and Ib is a flat line at 230. No changes whatsoever.
Here's our new circuit.

[image: basic bjt with dyslexic beta]

And here is a comparison between computed gain (using the correct formula, I've even thrown in alpha for good measure) and the simulated ratio of voltage.

[image: now they match, don't they]

Is this the sort of agreement you were looking for? I would call this a fairly good agreement.
Here, among the various quantities I have plotted you can see a zoomed version to appreciate the differences.

[image: the whole she-bang]

I forgot to say that I added a 50 ohm output resistance in the input signal generator, but do not worry, it didn't change the results in any significant manner.

To summarize, what was wrong was not the advanced model of the BJT, but the oversimplified gain formula that is based on - wait for it.... wait for it.... - the most basic model of BJT.

Now the ball is in your court: build the circuit on a breadboard, measure the temperature, measure the actual beta of your transistor and the values of the resistor at that temperature (wait a bit after having touched the case), re-simulate using those values and both the basic and advanced models of BJT and see which is closer to the experimental values. My money is on the more advanced model, but do not get your hopes up, if you wanna see real agreement you'd better be ready to create a model of the actual device in your hand.

One more thing: this biasing method is deprecated because the amplification depends heavily on the actual values of resistors and the actual beta, and most importantly on temperature. You will never use in a product because the tolerances on these values (especially beta) are more than enough to result in random amplification values and heavily temperature dependent operation. But once you have measured the values of your components at a given temperature, the reasons for the discrepancy you saw has nothing to do with that dispersion. It's just that you used a rule of thumb that's useful to get a ballpark estimate.

Comment: Thankyou . Now I understand but there is one point that I don't understand . Which model did you described above come from ? And please can you tell me How does formula above come from ?

Comment: @Heroz the model that fits with your calculation is the simple two port small signal model of the transistor. The hybrid pi, where the current ic is beta times ib. The model used by LTSpice is more complex and gives results that are close to reality. Just for fun, I breadboarded the circuit and after measuring the actual resistances and beta at the temperature my room was in, I got reasonable good agreement between measured values and LTSpice simulated values. (Not so much with microcap's simulation). Not sure if it was a sheer coincidence or if LTSpice is really that good of a simulator...

Answer (score 0):

I have simulated the circuit with PSpice (2N2222 and your parts values) and the result is gain A=56dB (-630).
The voltage Vce is Vce=9V and Vbe=0.66V.
Perhaps you should check your simulation arrangement?

**Correction:**
I had problems to identify the correct Rc value and have initially used Rc=6k. Only now I have seen that Rc is 5k only.

New results:
A=54.9dB (-556).

The voltage Vce now is Vce=12V and
Vbe=0.659V and  Ic=3.59mA.

Comment: Does your result is DC response when not apply ac signal ?

Comment: I simulated in Multisim .

Comment: @LvW...If I calculate gain from your result . re = 25mV/Ic. = 6.96.                      and I calculate voltage gain from                
           A= (r1//r3)/re = 683

Answer (score 0):

For reference, HFE and hfe are well "unknown" ...
Only some values are given, "min", "typical", and "max".

See this from the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00003223.pdf) ...
One can see the dispersion of HFE for Ic=10 mA (from 100 to 300),
and for hfe for 4 mA ... from "~ 60" to "~ 350" ("interpolated").

[image]

The problem is "probably" this one.
Just add a resistor RE= ~ 5 Ohm to your linearized circuit.
It is the value used by model "Mextram".
Simulation made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm), internal model "Mextram" available).

[image]